# Parametrization of a bounded solid.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, spherical-coordinates, solid-geometry

So, I have a solid bounded by $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}, z=2$

I had to parametrize it using spherical coordinates so I used
$$\begin{cases} x(\rho, \theta, \phi)=\rho\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\ y(\rho, \theta, \phi)=\rho\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\ z(\rho, \theta, \phi)=\rho\sin(\phi) \end{cases}$$
And
$$\begin{cases} \rho\sin(\phi)=\sqrt{\rho^2\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)+\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)} \\ \rho\sin(\phi) = \sqrt{1-\rho^2\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)-\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)} \\ \rho\sin(\phi)=2 \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} \phi=\pi/4 \\\rho=1\\ \rho=2/\cos(\phi) \end{cases}$$
So $\{(\rho, \theta, \phi)\in\Re^3 : 1\le\rho\le2/\cos(\phi)\land 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi \land 0 \le \phi \le \pi/4\}$

Maybe it can't be done with spherical coordinates but I wonder, could that solid be parametrized so that no variable is limited by a function as $\rho$ is?

Comment: This looks like the easiest way to describe the solid in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Spherical coordinates aren't a good choice because these are cones, and they meet way before $z=2$.

Comment: @user84413 I guess it would be complicated, I'm just asking out of curiosity if it's possible. I've tried but I get nowhere.

Comment: @MarkFantini z=sqrt(1-x^2-y^2) is actually a (hemi)sphere of radius 1, it was given to me like that so I chose to keep it.

Comment: Right, it's a hemisphere, my bad. But they still meet before $z=2$. To note it see that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{1-x^2+y^2} \implies x^2 +y^2 = 1-x^2-y^2 \implies x^2+y^2 = 1/2$ or $z=1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: So up to $z=1/\sqrt{2}$ you need to parametrize the cone in spherical coordinates, and in $1/\sqrt{2} \leq z \leq 1$ you parametrize the sphere.